# hidden and visibility corresponded to show() or css("visibility","visible")?

Tags: jquery

In a div, I have `<div id="test" style="visibility:hidden">`, I used `$('#test').show()`, it does not show up my `div`. But if I use `$('#test').css('visibility','visible')`, the `div` will show up.

`$('#test').hide()` will also hide my `div`, `$('#test').show()` will show up the `div`, I am wondering why both can `hide` div, but cannot use crossly?

Comment: `hide` and `show` methods works with `display` css property not with `visibility`. Try to use `<div id="test" style="display:none">`

Comment: `show/hide` manipulate CSS `display` property, not `visibility` one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally `visibility:hidden`  hides it but leaves the space or Its Still there allocating the space but not showing up .

That's why

`$('#test').show()` is not working  because `show()`works on elements **hidden with jQuery** methods and **display:none in CSS**. Not `visibility:hidden` And its working on `$('#test').hide()`

on the other hand

`display:none` means that the tag in question will not shown in  the page at all but you can still reach/use  it through the document object model/DOM). There will be no space allocated for it between the other tags.So Here You can Use  `$('#test').show();` as I mentioned you can interact with it

Finally In a nutshell :**if you set `display:none`, it hides the entire element, while `visibility:hidden` means that the contents of the element will be invisible, but the element stays in its original position and size & still affects layout.**

Hope It Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Visibility:hidden hides the targeted content, but it still keeps its place in the DOM : another element below it won't come at its place.

hide() also affects the DOM : the element's place is available for other content to be displayed at its place.

See this answer for example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/133064/4834168

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `hide` is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "none" )`. `show` works accordingly.